# Java command line error (linux) - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, linux, command-line, classpath, javac

I know that this a familiar and well-known issue that happens a lot.

Most of the time the issue is that the user did not specify the package if the class is in package. However I made sure that my case is different.

I tried the following

1- I made sure that the all the java files of the project are in the same folder (4 java files one with main class)

2- I made sure that non of the classes are in any packages

Then I tried to run the program as following (It is a storm hello-world example in case you are familiar with it)

1- Compile using the following command (The jar is needed for storm)

```
javac -classpath ~/Public/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar *.java
```

2- Run Main class using the following command (The jar is also needed here otherwise I'll get another error)

```
java -cp ~/Public/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar HelloStorm
```

What I get is the error below

> Error: Could not find or load main class HelloStorm

I double checked that HelloStorm is the name of the main class (with no spelling mistakes)

I am not familiar with running framework from command line .. so I might have missed something, however searching similar problem, reading oracle documentation and trying different approaches did not help unfortunately

What would you be your suggestions?

Comment: May be this detailed  solution might work     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: try running java -cp "~/Public/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar:." HelloStorm

Also, if HelloStorm is in a package say com.a.b, you will have to run it like: java -cp "~/Public/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar:." com.a.b.HelloStorm

Comment: which is the class with the `main` mehod?

Comment: @Anshuman when I do that .. it seems that the jar file is not loaded which cause an error

Comment: @Blip public class HelloStorm

Comment: are you sure 'HelloStorm.class' exists in the path from where you are issuing the `java` command?

Comment: @Blip Yes, all the classes are under the same repository that has "HelloStorm.class" .. I also double checked my location in the terminal and issued the "ls" command to make sure I am in the right place .. however still the same problem

Comment: update your question with the package details of HelloStorm and the complete path from where you are using the java command

Answer (score 0):

please check that if you have correctly written the main method like this

```
public class HelloStorm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think throwing an exception might cause any issue, right ? ... "public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ } "

Comment: No it should not be a problem. But this is a crude of way writing code. However, once I had faced issue with some situation. i cant remember the exact situation. But my suggestion is dont make this a practice.

Comment: just check that main method is exactly like this   

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

Comment: Throwing an exception that way may not be the best practice but it is just a helloWorld example that I did not write my self  ... Anyway I have double checked the main method signature, still same problem

Comment: test it without attaching the jar. just empty main method or with just System.out.println("Hello world statement");

Answer (score 0):

You compile to classes to your current location but you don't use it when you run program. Add it and it will run fine

```
java -cp .:~/Public/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar HelloStorm
```

If you are on Windows then class separator is semicolon. For Unix it is colon.

Comment: I received the following error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichSpout" ..... The error mean that the jar file was not read or loaded

Comment: If you are on Windows then class sepator is semicolon. For Unix it is colon. Also old versions of Java do not support -cp. Use full -classpth switch.

Answer (score 0):

While you want to execute a java program from command line given the following assumptions:

1. class name is HelloStorm
2. package is com.a.b
3. the directory in which the compiled class file is present is ~/Public/classes/com/a/b

To execute the program, you will have to be ~/Public/classes directory and execute the following command:

```
 java -cp ~/Public/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar com.a.b.HelloStorm
```